# kivy changing screen through pop up

Tags: python, kivy

I am opening a pop up on one screen and going to next screen by pressing the button on pop up, but the problem is it never goes to on_leave method of the first screen. In the code below, first screen is 'select', the popup is 'NextPopup' and the second screen is 'fast'.

Does anyone know about it?

Thanks in advance!

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.graphics.context_instructions import Color
from kivy.graphics.vertex_instructions import Rectangle
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.spinner import Spinner
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup



class NextPopup(Popup):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(NextPopup, self).__init__(**kwargs)        
        self.PopWindow(self)

    def PopWindow(self, instance):

        self.popbutton = Button(size_hint=(.2,.2), pos = (100,50))
        self.popup = Popup(content=self.popbutton, size_hint = (.5,.5), size = (100,100), auto_dismiss = False)
        self.popbutton.bind(on_press=self.popup.dismiss)
        self.popbutton.bind(on_release=app.change_screen)          
        self.popup.open()
        self.Windowclose(self)
        app.ok_btn_state = True
        print 'ok-btn-status', app.ok_btn_state
        app.next_btn_state = False

    def Windowclose(self, instance):
        app.sm.current = "fast"
        #app.change_screen(self)
        app.sm.switch_to('gs')           
        #app.ok_btn_state = False 

class GradeScreen(Screen):
    pass    


class FastScreen(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(FastScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_enter(self, *args):       
       print "s" 

    def on_leave(self, *args):        
        print "s" 

class LetterShape(Screen):    

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LetterShape, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.remain_layout = BoxLayout(id='remain_box',orientation = 'vertical',pos_hint = {'center_y': .5, 'center_x': .775 }, size_hint= (.46, 1), color = [0,1,0,1], spacing=0)
        self.add_widget(self.remain_layout)
        self.btn1 = Button(background_normal = 'ok.png', background_disabled_normal = 'dok.png', border = [1,1,1,1], text='Ok!', size_hint_y=.4,size_hint_x=.4, font_size=34,
        pos_hint = {'center_y': 1, 'center_x': .5 })
        self.btn1.opacity = 1
        self.btn1.disabled = False
        self.remain_layout.add_widget(self.btn1)        
        self.btn1.bind(on_press=self.call_popup)

    def call_popup(self, instance):
        a = NextPopup()

    def on_enter(self, *args):
        print  '...............on_enter.............'

    def on_leave(self, *args):
        print '..----------------------------------on leave.'

class CortestApp(App):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CortestApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self):
        self.Dialogue_state = 0
        self.slider_state = False
        self.ok_btn_state = False
        self.next_btn_state = False
        self.slider_state_counter = 0
        self.counter = 0        

        self.sm = ScreenManager(transition=FadeTransition())

        self.letter = LetterShape(name="select")
        self.sm.add_widget(self.letter)

        self.gradescreen = GradeScreen(name = "gs")
        self.sm.add_widget(self.gradescreen)

        self.fastscreen = FastScreen(name="fast")
        self.sm.add_widget(self.fastscreen)

        self.sm.current = "select"
        return self.sm



    def change_screen(self, instance):
        print "-------------------------------------------clear  -----------------------------------------------------------------"        
        #self.sm.current = "select"
        app.ok_btn_state = False
        app.next_btn_state = True        


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = CortestApp()
    app.run()


here is .kv
```

Comment: Documentation says "remove", try removing screen from ScreenManager's children, maybe then the function runs?

Comment: I want to use select screen again and again with a different plot every time, the problem is when I am doing this, its not updating the new graph. So I had to add 'fast' screen in between. Although in this code, I did not put plot in 'select' screen, to make it shorter. Also instead of popup, if am using another screen it works perfectly fine.